# How to prove that generating set for $S_n$ contain at least $n -1$ transpositions?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given a  Symmetric group $S_n$, I need to find the smallest generating set for $S_n$. I know it is given by $\langle S_n\rangle$, where

$$\langle S_n \rangle = \{(12),(13), \cdots,(1 n)\}$$
There are $n$ many transpositions in the generating set $\langle S_n \rangle $.

I know there are many generating sets for $S_n$, but I am only interested in those that contains only transpositions. For example $S_n  = \langle(1 2),(12\cdots n)\rangle$ is also a generating set for $S_n$ but it is not valid according to my problem.

> **My Question :** How to prove that generating set for $S_n$ contain at least $n - 1$ transpositions ?

Comment: $S_n=\langle(1\,2),(1\,2\,3\,\ldots\,n)\rangle$, so one transposition (and a cyclic premutaion) suffice ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe OP is looking for a generating set of transpositions, but the question is definitely unclear.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen and diracdeltafunk  In the question I have mentioned that transposition not cycle

Comment: @ diracdeltafunk What is thing that is unclear to you ?

Comment: Please separate items in a list with commas. Otherwise people are entitled to read them as products. So, for example, $(12)(13)$ is not a list of two transposition, but rather their product $=(132)$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks I will do that

Comment: Also $\langle S\rangle$ means the group generated by $S$. It is ok to write $\langle S_n\rangle$, but it is a bit strange, because the group generated by all of $S_n$ is obviously just $S_n$. In other words $\langle S_n\rangle=S_n$ trivially.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of transpositions as edges in a graph with vertex set
$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For the transpositions to generate $S_n$, this
graph must be connected.